# How to raise trap height for new vanity

Tags: plumbing, pvc, vanity

We are installing a new taller vanity. The opening cut into the rear by the manufacturer is higher than the existing wall connection and trap. To get the vanity to fit against the wall, I need to do a 90 degree angle immediately leaving the wall drain and go up. I would make the opening larger, but there are also two drawers on the bottom and a shelf above the drawers. The rear opening is above that shelf.

I can do all the plumbing and connections, but I need a diagram to the trap to accomplish correctly. How best can I accomplish the 90 angle using PVC leaving the wall drain opening. I have room for only a 3.5 inch stub leaving the wall. Is it OK to run a 90 degree bend at that location and do I need a stub segment going into the wall drain or can I connect directly with no stub?

Typically, most plumbers push the PVC pipe into that wall opening by 3 or 4 inches to ensure strength and no leaks.

Comment: pictures and/or diagrams please

Comment: Pictures preferred

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly, there is a 3.5" void between the back of the draws and the wall. You want to 90 down out of the wall and the install the p-trap parallel to the wall in this void space. Extend the top of the p-trap to the required hight with a 90 pointed towards the basin drain. Then use one last 90 to connect to the basin's outlet.

Answer (score 0):

pipe comes from the sink, the p-trap has to fall in line with the stub-out. If it falls below the stub-out then it will have to go uphill and will not drain It should be direct from the sink to stub-out if not it will affect the venting negatively. Frank